How to specialize on parameters other than `this` in Java
Consider the following example:
abstract class Numeric {
    abstract public Numeric add(Numeric other);
}

class Real extends Numeric {
     private double inner;

     public Real add(Real other) {
          return this.inner + other.inner;
     }
}

I am able to specialize on the return type (no doubt due to covariance), but the compiler (understandably) still yields an error since my implementation of add for a a mere Real is not sufficient to uphold Numeric's broader contract.
Is there a way to express in the superclass (e.g. Numeric) that implementers may specialize on parameters other than this, without using generics (since those make an orthogonal claim to mine, unless you consider only purerly static methods)?

isn't there extends Numeric missing?

What have you tried?  What's wrong with Real extends Numeric?

@user85421 Yes, I apologize. The question has been edited.

@markspace Using extends alone, I get the compiler error described in the question.

I think this is a job for generics:
public abstract class Numeric<N extends Numeric<N>> {
    public abstract N add(N other);
}

I realize that generic syntax is confusing.  The only reason I’m familiar with it is that java.lang.Enum uses it.  It is completely valid and normal and correct.
You can then use it like this:
public class Real
extends Numeric<Real> {
    private double inner;

    public Real(double value) {
        this.inner = value;
    }

    @Override
    public Real add(Real other) {
         return new Real(this.inner + other.inner);
    }
}


Is there a way to enforce that other and this share the same type in Numeric? This was the pitfall I observed with generics.

@WilliamRyman: No, that cannot be enforced in Java.  This is one of many reasons that trying to be generic over different types of numbers is not really a viable strategy in Java, and it is better not to try.

@LouisWasserman Damn, Java sucks. Sadly, we have to learn it for school. I don't know how industry can get by with such a woefully inadequate language that prohibits me from even expressing trivialities. :(

@WilliamRyman A fine time for you to learn that the things you are trying to express are indeed trivial. In the sense that they don't generally matter for the purposes of writing 'proper' code, where proper is objectively defined: It is easy to test, easy to read, easy to maintain, easy to modify in the face of the inevitable change requests. Coding is very difficult; being able to express such things is (evidently, by way of both java's success and the fact that while java is adding a ton of features every 6 months, this isn't even on the radar) not pertinent to that job at all.

@WilliamRyman as a particular example, trying to construct number systems by way of a type system that can express such things, starting off with Peano arithmetic for example feels all 'neat' and 'cool' and 'elegant', but is slow as molasses. In the end computers do int and long in the way java has them fast. That's kinda where that sentence ends. Generally the kind of highly arithmetic 'university level type wonk' constructions don't fare well once you move on from academia. Bring 'it has to perform' into it and all of a sudden what you want is intractably complicated.

@rzwitserloot Wouldn't the ability to express invariants such as the one I want to help you write proper code, given your definition? 1. It erradicates the need for runtime tests since it's a purely compile time construct, 2. it's makes the code more readable as it communicates intent precisely, 3. it eases maintenance and modification since the compiler will be better able to inform you where changes need to be made if you change an implementing subclass.

Not particularly.  The trick described in this answer is more than enough for realistic needs.  Generics are bad very specifically at working with numbers, which isn't really a problem: you don't need to switch numeric types pretty much ever in practice, certainly not in a way that'd require you to operate over the numeric types directly.  Industry has absolutely zero problem getting by with this.
